# Inserting Photos using a Loop: Deviation from Target Cell Incrementally Increases

Tags: excel, vba

I have to regularly make a report whereby a photo of each item used needs to be inserted into a specific position for printing. For example, if I use 3 items, I need to place a photo of each item in column A, row 6+(i-1)*23. I have tried using a loop and picture.insert but what always happens is that the first photo is perfectly placed while the second photo onwards gets incrementally deviated vertically. I would like to know if anyone has experienced this and if there are any solutions available. I apologize if there is already an answer but I was unable to find it. Also, apologies for the simplified code as I am typing from a mobile device.

```
For i=1 to lastRow
    Set targetCell = range(some range)
    Set pic = ws.pictures.insert(file name)
    With pic
        .Top = targetCell.Top
        .Left = targetCell.Left
    End With
Next i
```

Observations Part 1:

- this phenomenon occurs when I control the placement of the photos using a separate workbook, whether I use a loop or not
- without using a loop (pressing a button to execute the macro manually), the placement of the photos are perfect in Excel 2010 computers and are off horizontally (consistently) in Excel 2016 computers
- the abovementioned method involves writing the code in Excel 2016

Observations Part 2:

- I will start with solving the non-loop horizontal displacement issue before tackling the loop issue to try to better understand the problem
- it appears that the pixel size of each workbook are different, which could be the cause of the problem (different computers might have different pixel size definitions when the workbooks were created)
- for example, one workbook shows a 3.55 column width as 46 pixels while the other shows a 3.50 width as 49 pixels
- by copying a whole worksheet from one workbook and pasting it in another, I was able to make the pixel size of both workbooks consistent and that seems to have solved horizontal displacement (non-loop) issue
- the next step would be to try using the same workbook to implement the loops

Comment: So, using your example, first pic is in `A6`, the second is in `A29`, then `A52` ?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. I do not know if it helps, but the increasing deviation occurs downwards. For example, the second photo might be 5 pixels lower than its intended position, the third 10, and so on.

Comment: Could there be something resizing or otherwise altering the rows after the pictures are placed in the sheet?

Comment: There are no procedures altering the rows but I have made some new observations based on what you mentioned. I will edit my post to reflect that. Thank you for the ideas.

Answer (score -1):

I think the following should work:

```
For i = 1 To lastRow
    Set targetCell = ws.Cells(6 + (i - 1) * 23, 1)
    Set pic = ws.pictures.insert(file name)
    With pic
        .Top = targetCell.Top
        .Left = targetCell.Left
    End With
Next i
```

If there are still issues, it might be worth checking that the pictures don't include any blank/white pixel rows that make the image 'look' lower?

Comment: Thank you for your response. Unfortunately, it does not address my issue. Just to be sure, I have confirmed that there are no such “blank” pixels in all my photos.

Comment: Can you confirm you're using the code above and it's not working? I was wondering if the measurements for `.Top` and `.Left` were based on a different sheet (where perhaps the rows aren't identically sized) but in my code the use of `ws` would prevent that.